# Appropriate use of a 204 HTTP Status Code

Tags: rest, http, httpresponse

I am reading the RFC and can not quite determine if the following would be a suitable use of the 204 response code.

> The 204 response allows a server to indicate that the action has been
>      successfully applied to the target resource, while implying that the
>      user agent does not need to traverse away from its current "document
>      view" (if any).  The server assumes that the user agent will provide
>      some indication of the success to its user, in accord with its own
>      interface, and apply any new or updated metadata in the response to
>      its active representation.

I have a Controller that returns an array of x and y axis values to plot a graph from user historical data.

Assuming the user has no historical data or less than 2 points, a graph can not be plotted.

Should I:

1. Return a 204 with "NO_CONTENT" in the body.
2. Return a 200 and an object of empty x and y value arrays.
3. Return a 200 but with say "NO_CONTENT" or null body.

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: 204 itself means no content so your response body should be empty

Comment: I think this is mostly a matter of personal preference. I'd vote for 2 => 200 with empty array `[]` as response body.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be really specific with your response then you should check your conditions before sending the response and use the matching status code.

1. If the Controller returns an array. Then 200
2. If Controller doesn't have enough data to return. Then 204 with a message.

However, I would suggest using a 5xx status with a message if the second condition is true. But this is just my opinion and will depend on your specific use case.

Comment: Definitely not a 5xx.
5xx is when the server is in an unexpected error state.
My code determines there is not enough information so the server fully understands the request AND handles it appropiately without exceptions/errors.